# Qt call c++ method from java Activity

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qtandroidextras

How can I call a c++ method from a Java activity?
This is my Java code:

```
public class TestActivity extends QtActivity
{
  public native void resultRead(String maskedPan);

  @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
  {
    ... do something here with the received intent

    resultRead("result");
  }
}
```

This is my c++ code:

```
static void onResultRead(JNIEnv *env, jobject /*thiz*/, jstring value)
{
  qDebug() << env->GetStringUTFChars(value, nullptr);
}

void MyClass::registerJni()
{
  QAndroidJniEnvironment env;
  QAndroidJniObject javaClass("org/test/testproject/TestActivity");
  JNINativeMethod methods[] {{"resultRead", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", reinterpret_cast<void *>(onResultRead)}};
  jclass objectClass = env->GetObjectClass(javaClass.object<jobject>());
  env->RegisterNatives(objectClass, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
  env->DeleteLocalRef(objectClass);
}
```

When the Java code calls the resultRead function, my app crashes with this exception:

```
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectClass called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void android.os.Handler.<init>(android.os.Handler$Callback, boolean) (Handler.java:200)
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void android.os.Handler.<init>() (Handler.java:114)
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void android.app.Activity.<init>() (Activity.java:794)
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity.<init>() (QtActivity.java:94)
F art     : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   at void org.test.testproject.TestActivity.<init>() (TestActivity.java:12)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Not familiar with that use case but the error message seems to help: `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, do I have to call Looper.prepare() in the activity constructor?

Comment: I implement standard JNI_OnLoad function. It's used to register all native functions. I don't see it in your code. Look here for more details: https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-5/  Beware of this bug also: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70114

Comment: I just followed this guide: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-jnimessenger-example.html.
I'll try your method, thank you.